# Mac OSX Trouble Running pip commands

Tags: python, django, macos, pip

I recently installed Python 3.4 on my Mac and now want to install Django using pip. I tried running `pip install Django==1.7.4` from the command line and received the following error:

Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 232, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 347, in run
      root=options.root_path,
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 549, in install
      **kwargs
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in install
      self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 963, in move_wheel_files
      isolated=self.isolated,
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 234, in move_wheel_files
      clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 205, in clobber
      os.makedirs(destdir)
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
      mkdir(name, mode)
  OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django'

Obviously my path is pointing to the old version of Python that came preinstalled on my computer, but I don't know how to run the pip on the new version of Python. I am also worried that if I change my file path, it will mess up other programs on my computer. Is there a way to point to version 3.4 without changing the file path? If not how do I update my file path to 3.4?

Comment: try using pip3 or pip3.4 instead of pip

Comment: How did you install Python 3.4? Does `which pip3` give any output?

Comment: Wow that was simple! I used pip3 and it worked. Thanks for the help guys. @dazedconfused I reinstalled python 3.4 with homebrew because I read that it helped set up the appropriate file paths. 'which pip3' outputs /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/pip3. Should I be concerned that commands in the terminal default to python 2.7?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding sudo. `sudo pip install Django`

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a virtual environment. This can be achieved by using python modules like venv or virtualenv. There you can change your python path without affecting any other programs on your machine. If then the error is is still that you do not have permission to read files, try sudo pip install. But only as a last resort since pip recommends not using it as root.